# Showing image with variable src in tooltip of Highcharts scatter plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts, reactjs

I have a Highcharts scatter plot that I've managed to integrate into my react.js page, and it's happily showing ~15,000 points. On the tooltip, I wish to show an image based on the 'name' property of the point (each point has a unique name). This is what I'm doing:

```js
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  formatter: function() {
    return "<img src='https://image.deckbrew.com/mtg/multiverseid/'" + cardsRaw[point.name].multiverseids[cardsRaw[point.name].multiverseids.length - 1].multiverseid + "'.jpg' height='150'/>";                
  },
  followPointer: false
}
```

where `cardsRaw` is an array of objects keyed on the name, and `points.name` is the name of the point. Currently when I hover over any point it just gives me the series name and x and y coordinates, which I believe is the default behaviour. Based on other questions on this site, I can't see what I'm doing wrong? I even tried a static img src, but that didn't work either.

Comment: So nothing is happening. Where in the chart option is this? The root?

Comment: It's charts: plotOptions: scatter: tooltip.

Comment: Then try putting it in the root instead.

Comment: Now it's saying 'point is undefined'...

Comment: After reading the docs again, I realized this.point.name works.

Secondary question; is there any way of changing the tooltip contents on keyUp/keyDown events?

Comment: Instead of changing tooltip, why don't you include logic in tooltip formatter already? Something like `if (isKeyUp) { ... } else if (isKeyDown) { ... }` ?