# Showing different images in Highmaps when moving the mouse cursor to a point

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I'm trying to implement the next feature in Highmaps: when a user moves the mouse cursor to a specific point an image is displayed along with text data, you know, on any Highcharts chart, stock or map detailed information about point is appeared in a small window when a user moves the cursor on that point.

Problem is that I don't know how to insert images in these small containers - I think this post [Showing image with variable src in tooltip of Highcharts scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983462/showing-image-with-variable-src-in-tooltip-of-highcharts-scatter-plot) is somehow related to my problem, but there (and in the majority of questions concerning embedding images in Highcharts) users usually try to insert images statically into a legend or a tooltip and thus their tips are not helpful in my case.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Solution has successfully been found, too simple :), no more help needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can include required information in point, for example:

```
series: [{
  data: [{
    image: 'http://path.to/my/image.png'
  }]
}]
```

Then use formatter as described in your related question, but using `image` property:

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  formatter: function() {
    return '<img src="' + this.point.options.image + '" height="150"/>';                
},
```